# Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\jone\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am going to submit file in My Laravel application. this is My fileController

```
private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id)
    {

         //dd($request->only('task'));
        $file = new File;
        $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
        $file->project_id = $id;
        $file->task_id = $request->only('task')['task'];
        $file->save();
    }
```

and this is form.blade.php form acctions

```
action="{{ route('projects.files', ['project'=> $project->id, 'task'=>$task->id])}}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">  //this is line line 39
```

and route

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/files', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but got following error

```
ErrorException in 88ff5154a46f749c29024e0c9f84c577f7c5025e.php line 39: Undefined variable: task (View: C:\Users\john\Desktop\ddd\resources\views\files\form.blade.php)
```

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You will need to pass a `$task` to the `form.blade.php` from its controller.

Comment: The error message would be easier to read as a *block quote* (prefix with `> ` instead of four blanks). The line number does not help with not as many (non-numbered) lines of code presented. (Oh, a "line line" number comment *does* appear if and when one scrolls right in the second code block.)

Comment: how can I pass $task to the form.blade.php file?

Comment: anybody can tell me what is the way to pass $task to the form.blade.php

Comment: No any idea about this matter...